# How to crawl reviews from TripAdvisor api?

Tags: rest, api, tripadvisor

Is there any way to use REST for making GET/POST request to receive reviews in JSON/XML format?

Comment: search online, look at their docs https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/business-content/

Comment: The question is reasonable, I am myself looking for a solution for this problem. The API (the link pointed above) is not clear and has no mention of that.